# Detecting document keystrokes in Office-js

Tags: office-js, office365-apps

Is it possible to detect keystrokes in an Office Online document/workbook/presentation through officeJS, specifically for keystrokes involving character outputs on the document: alphanumerics, space, tabs, new line, etc.

Something similar to how we can add event handlers in javascript such as :

```
document.addEventListener('keydown' ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. There are no specific events to detect keystrokes. There are couple of things to note: Due to the asynchronous nature of the APIs, it is not possible to detect and act of the event in a synchronous fashion. The real-time detection and follow-up actions are not ideal use-cases for web based add-ins. However, you could detect changes at a higher level based on [data changed](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.bindingdatachangedevent) events. You'd have to determine what changed in the event handler and know that by then the change would have already taken place.